# How to make custom navigation view animations like this one

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, navigation-drawer

How can i achieve an animation for the Navigation view, like this one ?

[image]

So far, I think it is only possible by writing a custom Navigation View, the question is just how it should look like. Or is there another Option ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070831/can-i-open-the-drawer-layout-with-animation-programmatically

Comment: Please follow FlowingDrawer: https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer .  And also FlabbyListView : https://github.com/jpardogo/FlabbyListView . This might help you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[FlowingDrawer](https://github.com/mxn21/FlowingDrawer) is the answer of your question.

Add dependencies to your module level gradle :

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.mxn.soul:flowingdrawer-core:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
}
```

Define menu in your layout xml file

```
<com.mxn.soul.flowingdrawer_core.LeftDrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/id_drawerlayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"/>
```

[image]